# How to limit the line numbers of QTextBrowser

Tags: qt

I use `QTextBrowser` to show some execution information. I need to use hyperlinks so I choose `QTextBrowser`. Sometimes a series of more than 10000 lines will be sent to `QTextBrowser` per command execution.

`.setMaximumBlockCount()` is for restrict paragraphs, not for lines.I use one paragraph for a execution.

Comment: 1. What is line? One "line" may be drawn on several lines because of word wrapping.

Comment: 2. You may use qt html subset for improving text formatting: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/richtext-html-subset.html

Comment: @DmitrySazonov I use `insertHtml()` to insert a html string with ending of '<br />'. I call it a line here.

Answer (score 0):

There is no way to limit html "br"-lines with `QTextBrowser` functions. You have to implement it yourself, e.g. by count each "br" right before `insertHtml()` and remove extra lines.